# Why does `Locator` changes graphics depending on `ImageSize`?

Tags: manipulate, front-end, gui-construction, locator

This is driving me nuts. Consider this `Manipulate` command

```
points = RandomReal[{0, 2}, {10, 2}];
Manipulate[
 p1 = Graphics[{Red, PointSize -> Large, Point@points}, 
   PlotRange -> 3, Axes -> True];
 p2 = ContourPlot[Norm[{par1*x1, x2}], {x1, 0, 2}, {x2, 0, 2}, 
   ImageSize -> s];
 Grid[{{p1}, {Show[p2, p1]}, {loc}}, Alignment -> Left]
 , {par1, 0, 1}
 , {par2, 0, 1}
 , {{loc, {1, 1}}, Locator}
 , {s, 100, 300}
 , ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```

[image]

As far as I have always done something with `Locator`, it appears in the first graphic you display in `Manipulate` environments. If you just run my code, it does what I expected. But, when I change the size of the second graphic `p2` around the size of `p1`, the `Locator` jumps to `p2`.

[image]

Why??? How would you prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what to expect from Locator in this case so let's force it to be where we want to:

```
points = RandomReal[{0, 2}, {10, 2}];

Manipulate[
 p1 = Graphics[{Red, PointSize -> Large, Point@points}, 
   Epilog -> {Dynamic@Locator@Dynamic@loc}, PlotRange -> 3, Axes -> True];

 p2 = ContourPlot[Norm[{par1*x1, x2}], {x1, 0, 2}, {x2, 0, 2}, 
   ImageSize -> s];

 Grid[{{p1}, {Show[p2, p1]}, {Dynamic@loc}}, Alignment -> Left]
 , 
 {par1, 0, 1}, {par2, 0, 1}, 
 {{loc, {1, 1}}, None}, {s, 100, 300}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left
]
```

Notice the `Epilog` which is a convenient way to be sure that the `Locator` won't show in `Show`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I don't fully understand the problem, but I think Kuba's code is overly complex, and I can't see why the following simpler implementation of isn't a better approach.

```
SeedRandom[42];
pts = RandomReal[{0, 2}, {10, 2}];
Manipulate[
  p1 =
   Graphics[{Red, PointSize -> Large, Point@pts},
     PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}},
     Axes -> True,
     ImageSize -> s1];
  p2 =
    ContourPlot[
      Norm[{par1*x1, x2}], {x1, 0, 2}, {x2, 0, 2},
      ImageSize -> s2];
  Column[{LocatorPane[Dynamic @ loc, p1], Show[p2, p1]},
   Alignment -> Left],
  {{loc, {1, 1}}, None},
  {par1, 0, 1},
  {s1, 100, 300},
  {s2, 100, 300}]
```

[image: demo]

The only changes I made that are relevant to your problem are the use of `Column`, `LocatorPane`, and the control specification `{{loc, {1, 1}}, None}`. The other changes are only to get rid on irrelevant code and to make the graphics more compact for display on this site.

The reason for the locator jumping from one graphics object to another in you code is that the locator in seeking the largest graphics object in the content pane.

Comment: This is the simplest way to go about it: just wrap the image/plot of interest in `LocatorPane[]`, and set the corresponding `ControlType` to none.