# How to fix a locator to a desired plot of a Grid of plots?

Tags: locator

In my interactive demonstration there is a grid of plots, where 2 are 1D plots and the other 2 are contour ones. I need a locator placed in one of the contour plots to manipulate the parameters of the 1D plots. Below I give an oversimplified demonstrative code on which one manifestation of the problem is visible, and in the end my heavy real one in which it is manifested differently.

Here is the simple code:

```
        Manipulate[

 Grid[{{


    ContourPlot[(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*(1 - x^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -1, 
      1}, {y, -1, 1}],

    Plot[(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*(1 - x^2) /. x -> p[[1]], {y, -1, 1}, 
     PlotRange -> {-1, 2}]

    },

   {Plot[(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*(1 - x^2) /. y -> p[[2]], {x, -1, 1}, 
     PlotRange -> {-1, 2}],


    ContourPlot[(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*(1 - x^2), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}],

    }
   }],
 {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator}]
```

giving the following dynamic image:

[image]

One can see that the locator is in the first ContourPlot. Why? How to fix it such that it appears in the image of my choice? How to fix it such that it shows up in the both?

If I try to add the locator to the second ContourPlot:

```
   Manipulate[

 Grid[{{


    ContourPlot[(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*(1 - x^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -1, 
      1}, {y, -1, 1}],

    Plot[(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*(1 - x^2) /. x -> p[[1]], {y, -1, 1}, 
     PlotRange -> {-1, 2}]

    },

   {Plot[(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*(1 - x^2) /. y -> p[[2]], {x, -1, 1}, 
     PlotRange -> {-1, 2}],

    Show[{
      ContourPlot[(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*(1 - x^2), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}],
      Graphics[Locator[p]]
      }]
    }
   }],
 {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator}]
```

or to the both:

```
Manipulate[

 Grid[{{

    Show[{
      ContourPlot[(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*(1 - x^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -1,
         1}, {y, -1, 1}],
      Graphics[Locator[p]]
      }],

    Plot[(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*(1 - x^2) /. x -> p[[1]], {y, -1, 1}, 
     PlotRange -> {-1, 2}]

    },

   {Plot[(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*(1 - x^2) /. y -> p[[2]], {x, -1, 1}, 
     PlotRange -> {-1, 2}],

    Show[{
      ContourPlot[(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*(1 - x^2), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}],
      Graphics[Locator[p]]
      }]
    }
   }],
 {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator}]
```

I find that the second locator shows up, but when I try to move it, the both locators make a jump to the corner of the image or even outside the image. After the jump I only can move one of them.

The use of the `GraphicsGrid`istead of the `Grid` does not help.

In the previous example the locator showed up in the ContourPlot appearing first on my code. Please evaluate below my original code. By evaluating it one can make sure that here the locator shows up in the second ContourPlot.

```
trap = {{0, 0}, {0.05, 0.15}, {0.1, 0.15}, {0.15, 0}, {0, 0}};
incTrap = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}};

<< NDSolve`FEM`

bound = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> trap, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[incTrap]}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bound, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.00001];


    Manipulate[
     c = 150 - 2000*y;
     slv = NDSolveValue[{D[
           1.6*10^3*(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*(1 + c*(x - 0.075)^n)*
            D[\[CurlyPhi][x, y], x], x] + 
          D[1.6*10^3*(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*(1 + c*(x - 0.075)^n)*
            D[\[CurlyPhi][x, y], y], y] == 0, 
        DirichletCondition[\[CurlyPhi][x, y] == 19, y == 0.15], 
        DirichletCondition[\[CurlyPhi][x, y] == 0, y == 0]}, \[CurlyPhi][
        x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh];



     Grid[{{
        Show[{
          ContourPlot[
           Evaluate[
            1.6*10^3*(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*10^-5*(1 + 
               c*(x - 0.075)^n)*(D[slv, x]^2 + D[slv, y]^2)], {x, 
             y} \[Element] mesh, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
           ClippingStyle -> Automatic, 
           PlotLegends -> 
            BarLegend[Automatic, 
             LegendLabel -> 
              Style["J/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)]\)", 14, Black]],
            ImageSize -> 300, PlotLabel -> Style["Heat", 12], 
           ImageSize -> 150, 
           FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 16, Italic, Black], 
             Style["y", 16, Italic, Black]}],
          Graphics[{
            White, Thick, 
            Arrow[{{p[[2]]/3, p[[2]]}, {(0.45 - p[[2]])/3, p[[2]]}}],
            White, Thick, Arrow[{{0.075, 0}, {0.075, 0.15}}],
            Text[Style["y", 16, Italic, White], {0.08, 0.145}],
            Text[
             Style["x", 16, Italic, White], {(0.45 - p[[2]])/3 - 0.005, 
              p[[2]] - 0.005}]
            }]
          }],

        Spacer[20],
        Plot[Evaluate[
          1.6*10^3*(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*10^-5*(1 + 
              c*(x - 0.075)^n)*(D[slv, x]^2 + D[slv, y]^2) /. 
           x -> 0.075], {y, 0, 0.15}, PlotRange -> {0, 800}, 
         ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True, 
         FrameLabel -> {Style["y @x=0.075 (m)", 16, Italic, Black], 
           Style["Heat power (J/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)]\))", 
            16, Italic, Black]},
         Epilog -> 
          Inset[Column[{Row[{Style["Max=", 10], Style[Max[#], 10]}], 
               Row[{Style["Min=", 10], Style[Min[#], 10]}], 
               Row[{Style["Max-Min=", 10], 
                 Style[(Max[#] - Min[#]), 10]}]}] &[
            Table[Evaluate[
              1.6*10^3*(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*(1 + 
                  c*(x - 0.075)^n)*10^-5*(D[slv, x]^2 + D[slv, y]^2) /. 
               x -> 0.075], {y, 0, 0.15, 0.001}]], Scaled[{0.5, 0.8}]] ]

        },

       {Plot[{Evaluate[
           1.6*10^3*(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*10^-5*(1 + 
               c*(x - 0.075)^n)*(D[slv, x]^2 + D[slv, y]^2) /. 
            y -> p[[2]]],

          Evaluate[
           1.6*10^3*(1 + a*y + b*y^2)*10^-5*(D[slv, x]^2 + 
               D[slv, y]^2) /. y -> p[[2]]]}, {x, 
          p[[2]]/3, (0.45 - p[[2]])/3}, PlotRange -> {0, 1500}, 
         PlotStyle -> {Red, Directive[Blue, Dashed]}, ImageSize -> 300, 
         Frame -> True, 
         FrameLabel -> {Style["x @y on locator level (m)", 16, Italic, 
            Black], Style[
            "Heat power (J/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)]\))", 16, 
            Black]}],
        Spacer[20],
        ContourPlot[(1 - 3.38*y + 265.*y^2)*(1 + c*(x - 0.075)^2), {x, 
           y} \[Element] mesh, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
         ClippingStyle -> Automatic, 
         PlotLegends -> 
          BarLegend[Automatic, 
           LegendLabel -> 
            Style["\[Sigma]/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Sigma]\), \(0\)]\)", 
             14, Black]], ImageSize -> 300, 
         PlotLabel -> Style["Conductivity", 14, Black]]
        }
       }],
     {{a, -3.38}, -5, 15}, {{b, 265.}, -70, 
      300}, {n, {2, 4, 6}}, {{p, {0.075, 0.075}}, Locator}]
```

As much as I understand, the structures of the simple and original codes are equal to one another. Therefore, it is not clear, why it shows up in one or another image.

**So my question:** How to fix a locator to a desired plot of a Grid of plots?

I use Mma 11.1, Win7

Comment: What if you leave `{{p, {0, 0}}, None}` and use `Epilog -> {Dynamic@Locator@p}` in desired plots? p.s. related: [135587](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135587/5478)

Comment: @ Kuba  Thank you for the reference. Yes, this may be a way in a more simple case, or the approach proposed by m_goldenberg. However, in my original (rather than the demonstration) program the locator becomes much too "heavy" in that case, while in my initial code it is reasonably "smooth". By the way, m_goldenberg writes that Manipulate looks for the largest image available to put the locator into it. In my case (that is, in my original code) all the images were fixed to the same size.